# Before with past tenses

Tags: word-choice, tense

Which tense should I use here?

> There were documents in his briefcase which he needed to read before he was going (or went) in to work the next day?

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct, the 'he was' part isn't.

> There were documents in his briefcase which he needed to read before going in to work the next day.

or

> There were documents in his briefcase which he needed to read before he went to work the next day.